# Azure biztalk project in visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2012, biztalk

I am trying to install Azure biztalk services SDK and then create project in vs 2013 and vs 2015 community edition but dont see any project template.
I can only see project template for biztalk in vs 2012 professional. 
This is also made clear in the link here
http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=39087

However the issue is the microsoft doesnt sell vs 2012 online anymore and i dont see any reason in buying a 3 year old IDE when i have VS 2015.

So just checking if any one here has been able to create biztalk projects for azure in vs 2015.

Answer (score 2):

Its the same problem with Microsoft at Every Release of BizTalk and Visual Studio, the same question you asked get asked everytime 
I have VS 2010 but BizTalk project 2006R2 template doesn't appear
I have VS 2012 but BizTalk project 2010 template doesn't appear 
... 
You have to know that unfortunately BizTalk Project templates are not backward compatible this means that unless you have VS 2012 you won't be able to get those templates.
BUT There is maybe a chance that you can copy those templates from an existing install and get it on your computer (i'll try this at home and edit my answer later) i think it can work if it does i'll post this stuff